# Jquery dont work to display button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Goal:
Show the button "Candy Candy candy" after pressing the button text "Test2"

Problem:
It doesn't show the text and what part am I missing in order to complete it?

I have tried using on() and live() but it still doesn't work.

Info:
*I'm using jQuery and its ajax

Thank you!

```js
$('#test1').click(function() {
  document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML = "<button id='test2' type='button'>Test 2</button>";
});

$('#test2').click(function() {
  document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = "Candy candy candy !";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="test1" type="button">Test 1</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="data1"></div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="data2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `#test2` element doesn't exist at the point you attempt to bind the click event handler to it. You need to use a delegated event handler. I'd also suggest you use jQuery methods as you've already loaded it anyway, eg. `$('#data1').html('<button id="test2" type="button">Test 2</button>');`

Comment: Are you sure you want to include jQuery twice in two different versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use event delegation `on()` since the button was added automatically after the first click :

```js
$('#test1').click(function() {
  document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML = "<button id='test2' type='button'>Test 2</button>";
});

$('body').on('click', '#test2', function() {
  document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = "Candy candy candy !";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="test1" type="button">Test 1</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="data1"></div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="data2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to include jQuery twice in two different versions?

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @connexo , it was a mistake, fixed now

Comment: Glad I could help brother.